# Symfony2 Doctrine database into production

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Sorry if the question is one of a newb.

When I deliver my symfony2 website to my production webserver. I'm using a low cost hosting service. I cannot access mysql remotely ( only execute statement from their website through phpmyadmin ).

**Case 1:** Assuming I could access remotely, i should run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create --env=prod
```

with appropriate database settings so it would update my db.

**Case 2:** Assuming I can't access remotely, then i have two option:

- I could create an ugly script that would call the above line from the website and remove it after delivery.
- I could get the sql statement printed to a file and execute it. Which seems better to me.

**Question:**

- Is there a pb with the above ?
- Is there a way to get an sql script in a file from:

  php app/console doctrine:schema:create --env=prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dump the sql statement using the --dump-sql option, and store it in a file:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql > statement.sql
```